# Git checkout commit command works like git reset commit

Tags: git, version, commit, git-checkout, git-reset

I want just to see my previous commits without doing any changes.

I use:

```
git checkout id_of_certain_commit
```

But when I try to get back, it looks like everything that was from that point is removed. I use:

```
git checkout master
```

It does not get back to the commits that were ahead...

Please, help. It looks like I am doing something wrong

Comment: I think you *meant* to run `git checkout <hash>`, but *actually* ran `git reset <hash>`. That's not what your question states, but it would explain what I'm guessing you meant by "It does not get back to the commits that were ahead" (which is otherwise unclear).

Answer (score 0):

In Git, "checking out" means making a certain state your current working state: the actual files in your Working Copy will be the ones from that exact point in time. So - unlike reset - you are not unstaging anything but just "going back in time"...

What you are looking for is probably this:

```
git show <commit_id>
```

Note: To undo `git checkout` do `git checkout -`